# Gravity at the interior poles inside a large spinning sphere?

Tags: technological-development, dyson-spheres, microgravity, artificial-gravity

From other answers I've determined that gravity on the interior of a large spinning sphere (like a Dyson Sphere) could create a desired gravity at the equator at the inner surface.

But what would gravity be like on the inside poles of the sphere? What would happen in the areas just below the north pole or just above the south pole? Would gravity gradually fall off until you had low/no gravity? Might you be spinning in that area? Would objects just float around in those areas?

Comment: What you're describing is basically an O'Neill cylinder, except that it's shaped like a sphere instead of a cylinder. Reading about the cylinder kind will probably give you an equivalent answer. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%27Neill_cylinder )

Comment: @Qami also consider the [Bernal sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernal_sphere) which is a spherical design, strangely enough. Slightly predates O'Neill's work, too.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Thanks! Hadn't come across that one.

Comment: the effects of gravity anywhere inside a hollow sphere is zero. see the shell theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say, the nearer you are to the axis (which intersects the inner surface at each pole) the lower the apparent gravity -- and further, given you're inside a sphere, the direction of that force will be nearly parallel with the "ground" -- making it very hard to keep your footing (like trying to stand on the side of a building, albeit in near microgravity conditions).

If you're close enough to the spin axis, you could jump or throw something hard enough to kill its spin velocity entirely; it would seem to go into and orbit, though in fact it would be standing still relative to the axis (as least until air movement accelerates it enough to start falling outward again).

Answer (score 2):

If the inside of the sphere is empty, then gravity at the poles would be exactly zero.

If the inside of the sphere is **not** empty, like a typical Dyson Sphere, then the gravity on the inside surface at the poles would be **negative**. You would fall off towards the central star.

So obviously you move to the outside of the sphere. Now the gravity on the pole is nice and well-behaved, pointing directly down.
As so as you start walking in any direction, the apparent slope under your feet increases. much, *much* more quickly than the curvature of your sphere, even if that sphere was on an infinite flat gravity world. By the time you are about 30 degrees away from the pole, the gravity vector is no longer pointing towards the shell of the shere, but away from it.

This is because the true gravity is always pointing down towards the core of the system, thus also towards the center of the sphere, but centrifugal force is trying to fling you laterally, away from the axis of rotation (!not away from the center!).
The sum of these two vectors is what you feel, and this resultant will appear to rotate through 180 degrees as you walk over 90 degrees of the sphere to its equator.

(explanatory picture may follow, if reader's confusion exceeds my lack-of-artistic-talents)

Answer (score 1):

What one perceives as gravity in a rotating shell is due to the centrifugal force, which can be calculated as $F=\omega^2 \cdot r$.

As you can see, when one is at the pole, $r=0$ and therefore $F=0$. However, since $r=0$ applies only to a line and a person is larger than a line, there will be a non zero force, which is nonetheless negligible unless the rotation is very rapid.

Comment: Need to factor in that the OP is talking about a *dyson* sphere, which is defined as a sphere around a central mass, a sun. This will always exert true gravity radially inwards, which interacts with the centrifugal effect of rotation.

Comment: But, @PcMan, it's (said to be) easy to show that gravity due to the mass of the sphere itself is zero anywhere inside the shell.  If you're inside, and the shell spins, the water and air will all be at the equator (and if you build the thing out of something a thousand times stronger than *scrith* you might get up to 1G out there), but you'll have zero G (due to spin and shell, i.e. neglecting the star at the center) at the axis.

Comment: @ZeissIkon YEp. But only if you are *inside* the sphere, and there is no gravity source more "inside" than you are. For a true Dyson sphere, 99.9999999999etc% of the mass will still be at the center, the star.

Comment: @PcMan Of course.  Now, go calculate what the Sun's gravity is at the Earth's orbit.  Hint: it isn't all that much.  And if you can build a self-supporting sphere, 90-100 million miles radius, I bet it'll mass more than Jupiter.  Besides, the tech to keep the star centered makes everything else look like child's play.

Comment: @ZeissIkon YES! That's why you will "fall off" the sphere's outer surface before you even reach 30 degrees from the pole. And NO, you cannot have it mass much more than all the planets combined, unless you provide SunDiver level tech to get the materials. Rather postulate Scrith or equivalent, which makes **any** guesstimating of the total mass needed an exercise in sillyness.

Comment: @PcMan Magnetic boots to the rescue.